# Bash Script is returning non-zero status

Tags: linux, bash, vagrant

I'm trying to install `beanstalkd` on an Ubuntu 14.04 LTS system.  Seems to go okay, except for the following is giving me non-zero return status.  Vagrant halts once this occurs and I have other scripts to install after wards that don't run.

I've tried

```
grep -q "START=yes"
grep --quiet "START=yes"
grep "START=yes" > /dev/null
```

non seem to suppress the output of GREP

```
echo -n "Checking /etc/default/beanstalkd for beanstalkd startup line           ... "
if [ -f /etc/default/beanstalkd ]; then
    echo -n "START=yes is"
    grep "START=yes" /etc/default/beanstalkd > /dev/null
    if [ $? = 0 ]; then
        echo -n "..already present"
    else
        echo -n "START=yes" >> /etc/default/beanstalkd
        echo -n "..Added to /etc/default/beanstalkd"
    fi
fi
echo "Done!"
```

**Result :**

```
==> default: Checking /etc/default/beanstalkd for beanstalkd startup line           ... 
==> default: START=yes is
The SSH command responded with a non-zero exit status. Vagrant
assumes that this means the command failed. The output for this command
should be in the log above. Please read the output to determine what
went wrong.
```

Comment: if GNU, you must have two dashes: `--quiet`.

Comment: Have you tried `grep -q` to suppress output?

Comment: @amphetamachine, the original post says yes, he did try it.

Comment: `-q` doesn't silence errors, such as a missing file.  For complete silence under `bash`, `grep "START=yes" /etc/default/beanstalkd &>/dev/null`

Comment: you haven't told us the most important part, is `START=yes` already in the file or not? What does `grep "START=yes" /etc/default/beanstalkd` return? Also, don't you want an `else` condition to the first `if` test that will add `Start=yes` to a newly created `beanstalkd` file? Good luck.

Comment: @Shellter the expectation is that the line does NOT exist.. however I need to return a non-zero status code either way.

Comment: line is file does NOT exist, good. Do you expect that the file is there? (Note my update to original comment). Good luck.

Comment: @shellter above this is a `sudo apt-get -qqy beanstalkd` .. yes I expect the file to exist.  If NOT then I would want an error.  See my update on output

Comment: That sounds like the script is being run with `set -e` active. In which case you need to avoid a simple command returning non-zero. The if usage in @amphetamachine's answer will do that for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following invocation of grep will suppress *all* grep output (both stderr and stdout). No warnings, no errors, nothing.

```
grep -q "START=yes" /etc/default/beanstalkd >/dev/null 2>&1
```

If your query was about the `if [ $? = 0 ]; then` line not working as expected, you can replace it with this:

```
if grep -q "START=yes" /etc/default/beanstalkd >/dev/null 2>&1; then
    # already present
```

Comment: the first line you gave did not suppress the error message.  I'm going to try splitting off this grep call into a script that calls `exit 0` at the end, and continuing with the rest of my work in a second script.

Comment: I take it back.. your 2nd line , combining the `if` worked great!  Thank you